# Translation of HTML formulas into Latex

Tags: html, latex

I am trying to copy formulas from a website into stackoverflow. However - when i copy the formulas from e.g. http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html - i get code the looks like Latex - but is not represented as such. is there any way to automatically translate HTML formula code in Latex that is suitable for stackoverflow? (example below)

$\frac{\partial \log p(x)}{\partial \theta} &= \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}(x)}{\partial \theta} - \sum_{\tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x}) \ \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}(\tilde{x})}{\partial \theta}$

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX is supported on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (and a few others), but not on **Stack Overflow**.

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow

You can use images and post the image of the LaTeX instead. Here is a LaTeX to PNG converter: http://latex2png.com/

Example:
[image: Example LaTeX]